# g++ doesn't compile certain nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, nested

When BREAK is defined, g++ 4.7.2 will not compile the following, which I think is valid C++. It does compile with BREAK defined if the `A<U> tmp` is changed to something else, like `A<int> tmp` - while that makes the minimal test case here work, it's no good in my actual application. Is there anything here that is not legal C++?

```
template <typename T>
class B {

};

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    template <typename U> B<U> *alloc_B( );
};

template <typename T> template <typename U>
B<U> *A<T>::alloc_B( ) {
    return new B<U>( );
}

#ifdef BREAK
template <typename T>
class C {
public:
    template <typename U> void x(B<U> &b) {
        A<U> tmp;
        B<U> *tmp2;
        tmp2 = tmp.alloc_B<U>( );
        delete tmp2;
    }
};
#endif

int main( ) {
    A<int> a;
    B<float> *bp = a.alloc_B<float>( );
    delete bp;

#ifdef BREAK
    C<int> c;
    B<float> b;

    c.x(b);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alloc_B` function template is a dependent name. You must call it as so:

```
tmp2 = tmp.template alloc_B<U>( );
```

That's the problem, and that is why it works when you use `A<int>`, because the type no longer depends on the template argument `U`.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to one of `C++`'s annoying parsing rules. When it sees `tmp.alloc_B<U>`, this is not interpreted as a template, but as `tmp.alloc_B < U`. To fix this, you need to explicitly specific this is a template:

```
tmp2 = tmp.template alloc_B<U>( );
```